# Hibernate @NamedQueries with reserved word

Tags: java, hibernate, reserved-words

I have a problem with hibernate @NamedQueries. I Have a table SCP_PMAT with Column named 'group'. In mapping isn't problem. This I solve with brackets.

```
public class ScpPmat{
    @Column(name = "[group]")
    private String group;
}
```

But when I want to use @NamedQuery there is a problem. How can I write column name to query?

```
@NamedQuery(name = "readScpPmatByGroup",
query = "FROM ScpPmat where group = :group")
```

Hope this code is sufficient.
Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it's satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Best option: change the name of the column to not be a reserved word.  Its generally bad practice to do so, and can cause headaches in both Java code and SQL, as per what you're experiencing.

Another option would be to change the Java field name from the reserved word to a non-reserved word, like `groupCol`.

Comment: Sure, that is the best. Lets talk to our database 'specialist'

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the reserved word in quotes:

```
query = "FROM ScpPmat where \"group\" =:group")
```

Comment: I tried this but with this exception  `Error in named query: readScpPmatByGroup
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [FROM core.dao.ScpPmat where "group" = :group]`

Comment: I tried it with the brackets too.. ..but the same exception.. :-/